# Proper way of using contain

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq the row if the `DiffDays`> 3, it will be included.
But  I have this another condition where If the ID does not exist in the other table, it will be included.

I have tried using this code but it doesn't work:

```
var stock = (from x in db.Stock
            where (!(from re in db.Reserve select re.StockID).ToList().Contains(x.StockID)) 
            || DbFunctions.DiffDays(DateTime.Now, y.DateReserved) > 3
            select x);
```

What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Any` like this:

```
(from x in db.Stock
        where !db.Reserve.Any(re => re.StockID == x.StockID)
        || DbFunctions.DiffDays(DateTime.Now, y.DateReserved) > 3
        select x);
```